# Asp response.redirect not redirecting

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect, asp-classic

I have a Login popup form where I send ajax post request to Login.asp script to prevent go to POST URL after submit.

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url:'/ASPLogin/Login.asp',
            type:'POST',
            data:$('#contactForm').serialize(),
            dataType:'text',
            success: function(response)
            {
            var temp = new Array();
            temp = response.split("|");

            if (temp[0] == 'something') {

              }
              else {

                  $("#response").html(response);
             }
            }
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

in Login.asp

```
If OK Then
 response.redirect("/index.asp?token=" & str)
Else
 response.write("error")
End If
```

So when login is wrong I put Error message into popup form, if login is OK then I need to close popup form and redirect.

But I get redirected page sources inside my popup form.

I tried to do like that

```
If OK Then
 response.write("<script>$('#closeBut').click();</script>")
 response.redirect("/index.asp?token=" & str)
Else
 response.write("error")
End If
```

Popup is closed but page is no redirected

I tried to do like that

```
If OK Then
 response.write("<script>$('#closeBut').click();</script>")
 Response.Write("<script>window.location.href = " & "'/index.asp?token=" & str & "';</script>")
Else
 response.write("error")
End If
```

Popup is closed but page is no redirected

How to fix that? How to close popup and redirect page normally?

Comment: you can't be redirected when ajax request is successful. means under `success: { (perform redirect from here) window.location = url }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server side redirection won't affect the browser itself when the request is made from ajax, only the ajax request object will see the redirected page source in the response.

You need to response.write the url so that you can make a client-side redirection

For example:

```
If OK Then
 response.write("/index.asp?token=" & str)
Else
 response.write("error")
End If
```

then in the ajax success event:

```
success: function(response)
{

    if (response != 'error') {
        location.href = response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that only redirect but not close a popup

Comment: use window.opener.location.href to redirect in opener window, and then window.close() to close the popup